# Flutter : smooth video streaming in videoplayer

Tags: flutter, video-streaming, bitrate

I am making an application which needs to stream videos stored at a server.
When i play the video it buffers a lot. Is there anything i can do to make the streaming smoother without losing much of the quality?

Video format: mp4, mov
Flutter video player version: video_player 0.10.11+1
Server : hostinger business server the bandwidth unlimited.

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Please provide more information like video format, player information, server information, bandwidth etc.